# Printing a warning message over multiple lines

Tags: matlab

I am trying to print a warning message that is a little long and includes 2 variable calls. Here's my code:

```
warning( 'MATLAB:questionable_argument', ...
           'the arguments dt (%d) and h (%d) are sub-optimal. Consider increasing nt or decreasing nx.', ...
           dt, h )
```

Obviously, the line of text extends to the right when viewing the MATLAB code. How can I break it so it wraps nicely? I've tried multiple things but keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Insert `\n` in the string? (not sure If I got the question correctly)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in comments, just insert a `\n` where you want to break the line. You can also use a variable for the text, to make it easy to read also within the code:

```
txt = sprintf(['the arguments dt (%d) and h (%d) are sub-optimal.\n'... 
    'Consider increasing nt or decreasing nx.'],dt,h);
warning( 'MATLAB:questionable_argument',txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just embed escape characters such as `\n` in a warning string, it will not work:

```
warning('Hi there.\nPlease do not do that.')
```

will just print out:

> Warning: hi there.\nPlease do not do that

However, if you pre-format the text using `sprintf` , then all the escape characters will work. For instance:

```
warnText = sprintf('Hi there.\nPlease do not do that.');
warning(warnText)
```

Produces what you want:

> Warning: Hi there.
>   Please do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple version than EBH had provided is as shown:

```
str1 = 'text 1';
str2 = 'text 2';
str3 = 'etc.';
str = sprintf('\n%s \n%s \n%s \n',str1,str2,str3);
warning(str)
```

Comment: Which part is "more simple" ?